# Problems updating part of '000s of workbook links

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 9 sheets, where each sheet contains 500 rows, about 120 columns and references about 25 other workbooks.

The workbooks have moved directory en masse, and so the path all these workbooks are on has changed from:

S:\Path\Path\Path\Workbook.xlsx to
S:\Path\Path\PathNew\Workbook.xlsx

I'm trying to write a macro that will change all the paths quickly, because using Update Link or Find and Replacing all the text slows down Excel to a crawl and seemingly never wants to finish.

I've tried looking online and found what looked like a nice bit of code, but I think it's not working because the workbook links aren't technically hyperlinks.

```
Dim lnkH As WorksheetDataConnection
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String

sOld = "\FY20\"
sNew = "\FY20\STX FC @ April Update\"

For Each lnkH In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    lnkH.Address = Replace(lnkH.Address, sOld, sNew)
    lnkH.TextToDisplay = Replace(lnkH.TextToDisplay, sOld, sNew)
Next
```

My VBA skills aren't excellent - I normally find stuff I need online and then tweak for my own purposes. Is there an equivalent version of the above that will update the thousands of workbook links in a way that doesn't crash my PC for hours?

Comment: I guess those links are related to calculations later on. Maybe setting up Calculation to manual, then use your macro, and then set calculation to automatic again.

Comment: [`Workbook.ChangeLink` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink)

Comment: I've looked at that, but wasn't sure if it was possible to change just the left most part of a link. Do you know if it works with LEFT at all?

Comment: You take the full old name of the link, you come up with the full new name based on `sNew`, you provide the full new name to `ChangeLink`. You are doing exactly that in your attempt to change `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks`.

Comment: Will this work independently of the workbook names? So could I define the change for the left hand part of the address only, or do I need to do it for all 20 workbooks?

I guess I could do an if, loop through a single list of the workbook names and then apppend it based on the incoming address

Comment: You can just use Replace(oldfullpath,nameofoldfolder,nameofnewfolder) to get new full path

Comment: Under certain circumstances, I've found that setting a *Hard Link* or *Symbolic Link* to the new location is easier than changing the formulas in Excel that refer to those files/locations.